# console application settings using batch file

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file

I have created a console application which sends emails to people by selecting their email addresses from database. I have used entity framework for database connectivity. I have stored connection string and SMTP settings in app.config. I have called this application exe from a batch file. I have called this exe file of console application from a batch file. I have provided client with exe and batch file. This exe uses my gmail smtp settings and connection strings. How can client update the connenction string and SMTP settings of this EXE ? Are there any options in batch file to build the exe when settings are changes in app.config ? Please suggest.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 2):

The entire purpose of the .NET configuration feature is that you do *not*  have to rebuild the application.

When you properly use the application settings, a file `xyz.exe.config` is created in the output folder (where the `xyz.exe` is after compiling). Just copy the `xyz.exe`, the `xyz.exe.config` and the batch file to the client and change the values in the `xyz.exe.config` file accordingly.

Comment: I"m not sure if the OP gets that you need to add an application configuration file support (App.Config). Also for the OP, you'll need to add a reference to System.Configration.

Answer (score 1):

App.config settings are runtime settings -> they will be read when running the application (not when compiling).
This means that if you modify the settings inside app.config they will be visible/read the next time the application is launched.

When you compile the app.config will be converted to *YourConsoleApplicationName*.exe.config (e.g. my console application is called ConsoleApp1, the generated exe will be *ConsoleApp1*.exe and the config file will be *ConsoleApp1*.exe.config) so make sure you distribute this along with the exe and bat (the .exe.config should reside in the same directory as the .exe).

Once the client gets the above files he/she can modify the settings inside the config file and deploy the application with the modified settings inside it's network

You could modify your batch file to modify the content of the app.config before running your application (e.g. switch depending on the authenticated user), but this seems too much trouble (doesn't really make sense because you could do all this easier from the console application).